# RESTful API communciation from Ruby on Rails (4.0)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, node.js, rest, event-handling

We are working on a RoR project implementing an LMS. We need to send data to an external REST service provided by an external server. The data is sent when certain events are accomplished, it is possible that some of those are not triggered by the client (clicks, etc.).

Also, we need to keep consistency in our rails models, because we need to keep record of the user activities.

There is a library provided to work with the API, written in JavaScript. It makes most of the work easy, so we would like to use instead of creating our own implementation for the API requests.

What are the differences between each of the following approaches? Would one be preferable to another?

1. Use javascripts to send the data, inserting the snippets in the
   views, from the client, but having the client execute this might have
   some serious implications (scores changed, false success, etc).
2. Use a NodeJS server to execute the Javascript but we don't really know how to communicate with our main server (Rails)
3. And finally, use a HTTP client from the Rails app to send the requests to the service. However we don't know exactly how to do it, also there is the question of where this code goes in the MVC pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option #1, as you've likely realized, is out of the question. For the client to make API calls on your behalf, you would need to send them your secret key/token/whatever you need to authenticate with the API. But once they have that, they could just use a script console to make whatever API calls they want "as you". This would be pretty disastrous.

Option #2 might be prohibitively complex -- I'm personally not sure how you'd go about it. It is possible, using a library like [therubyracer](https://github.com/cowboyd/therubyracer), to execute JavaScript code from Ruby code, but there is some degree of sandboxing and this may break code that requires network access.

That leaves you with Option #3, writing your own Ruby library to interact with the API. This could be easy or difficult, depending on how hairy the API is, but you already have a JavaScript version on hand (and hopefully docs for the REST service itself), so combined with something like [RestClient](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client) or [HTTParty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty) the path forward should be clear.

As for where the API calls would fit in your Rails code: If you have models that are basically mirroring the resources you're interacting with through the REST service, it might make sense to add the relevant API calls as methods or callbacks on those models. Otherwise it might be fine to put them in the relevant controller actions, but keep an eye on your code complexity and extract to a separate class or module if things are getting ugly.

(In cases where you don't need to wait for the response from the API before sending something back to the user, you may want to use [DelayedJob](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) or similar to queue your API calls in the background.)